# Error in Mono Compiler: Files in libraries or multiple-file applications must begin with a namespace or module declaration

Tags: f#, mono, compiler-errors

I am trying to compile [this example](http://www.expert-fsharp.com/CodeSamples/Forms/AllItems.aspx?RootFolder=/CodeSamples/Chapter16/Example05&FolderCTID=&View=%7BA3A504F7-2915-4C7D-B25B-D7EE5B750475%7D) in mono on ubuntu.

However I get the error

```
wingsit@wingsit-laptop:~/MyFS/kitty$ fsc.exe -o kitty.exe  kittyAst.fs kittyParser.fs kittyLexer.fs main.fs 
Microsoft (R) F# 2.0 Compiler build 2.0.0.0
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All Rights Reserved.

/home/wingsit/MyFS/kitty/kittyAst.fs(1,1): error FS0222: Files in libraries or multiple-file applications must begin with a namespace or module declaration, e.g. 'namespace SomeNamespace.SubNamespace' or 'module SomeNamespace.SomeModule'

/home/wingsit/MyFS/kitty/kittyParser.fs(2,1): error FS0222: Files in libraries or multiple-file applications must begin with a namespace or module declaration, e.g. 'namespace SomeNamespace.SubNamespace' or 'module SomeNamespace.SomeModule'

/home/wingsit/MyFS/kitty/kittyLexer.fsl(2,1): error FS0222: Files in libraries or multiple-file applications must begin with a namespace or module declaration, e.g. 'namespace SomeNamespace.SubNamespace' or 'module SomeNamespace.SomeModule'
wingsit@wingsit-laptop:~/MyFS/kitty$
```

I am a newbie in F#. Is there something obvious I miss?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As Brian and Scott pointed out, you need to enclose the file in a namespace or module declaration. Just adding `namespace SomeNamespace` may not work if you have top-level `let` binding in the file (as these must be in some module). The following would be invalid:

```
namespace SomeNamespace
let foo a b = a + b   // Top-level functions not allowed in a namespace
```

That said, I prefer having `namespace` instead of `module` at the top-level and then wrapping all functions in a `module` explicitly (as I believe that makes code more readable):

```
namespace SomeNamespace
module FooFunctions =     
  let foo a b = a + b
```

But of course, you can add top-level module as Brian suggests (earlier versions of F# automatically used the name of the file in *PascalCase* as the name of top-level module used in the file):

```
// 'main.fs' would be compiled as:
module Main
let foo a b = a + b
```

Answer (score 3):

You can probably fix it up by adding

```
module theCurrentFileName
```

to the top of each .fs file.

Indeed, this is a newer requirement, and the sample is old and needs updating.

Answer (score 2):

Old question, but i reached it for the same problem and i want to add hint for module in F# 3.

In multiple-file applications, you needn't to use namespace, but you should use module

Top-level module declaration, declared in this way (without equal sign =)

```
 module module_name
 //Not
 module module_name =
```

Local Modules in the same file, use "="
example:

```
 module toplevel        // top level module without "="

 module module1 =      // local module with "="
   let square x = x*x

 module module2 =
   let doubleit x = 2*x
```

- You do not have to indent declarations in a top-level module.
- You do have to indent all declarations in local modules.

Answer (score 0):

This problem arises because those sample files were written for a version of F# that didn't have that requirement.

As the error message explains, all you need to do is to add `namespace SomeNamespace` to the top of each file, and it will compile just fine. Even in mono on ubuntu.